# Image not loading in iPhone6

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a background image in one of my element (code is on a separate file, style.css), it loads fine in most of the devices (iphone5, iphone5c, samsung galaxy), BUT NOT in iphone6 and iphone6plus (and some of ipad). Do you guys have any idea why?

```
.content-block {
  background-image: url('image/img.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-position: center center;
  min-height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: without code we can't help.

Comment: Are you setting the height and width of the div somewhere?

Comment: First and foremost as @thepio said, your element which you are applying a background to, should have set dimensions. E.g. > height: 500px, not min-height, because it will not display your background since it is "not there".

Comment: @Sqnkov yep, I am just a little confused about the "it loads fine in most of the devices" part. Might just be that there is some other code that is not posted in the question and is affecting the output.

Comment: Yes, I doubt that there is a device-specific project at hand here. Just gave you two upvotes @thepio

Answer (score 0):

For a start, try using the shorthand version which allows for a more consistent background setting.

```
background: url('../image/img.jpg') no-repeat center center / cover;
```

As you can see I added `../` before your image directory, just in case the browser can't find its way to it.

> You can find more thorough explanation about CSS shorthand usage which I am referring to, at the [**Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties)